# How to find out CPU utilization per Oracle Database on Linux?

Tags: linux, oracle

For capacity planning on existing RedHat servers hosting Oracle Databases, I was asked how to find out the CPU utilization per database.

Thought it would be as simple as

```
ps -eo pcpu,comm |grep -i oracle_dbname
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: Do you need to do this through the command line? The enterprise manager shows this information on it's console.

Comment: Victor- Thanks for your comments. Unfortunately, I'm a SysAd and have to stick with command line to make it scripted across all the servers but I'll check with my fellow DBA friends on this.

Answer (score 2):

All the oracle processes are kicked off by the `oracle` executable, and if you're running multiple databases on a server, all of the processes for each database will show up with just that executable.

Adding the `args` option to the `ps` command will add the database name both for the instance processes (such as `pmon`) and server processes (those satisfying user activity) to the `ps` output to allow grepping.

What I don't know is what you'll get is useful, considering `ps` is a snapshot of activity as of a given instant in time, and that seems like a very strange way to do capacity planning.

Comment: Thx Adam. Even I doubt 'ps', but would welcome any other command line tool for that matter.